# How can I choose which media player to use when continuing playback via headphone or Google Assistant?

Tags: google-assistant, media-player

I've got several apps to playback stuff on my Android device (Google News, Spotify, Audible). Usually, all these media players stick to the notification menu / quick settings.

When pausing playback either via Google Assistant voice command or button on my Pixel Buds and then resuming, most of the time, the most recently used media player continues to playback.
However, sometimes (and then in situations in which I am unable to operate my phone by hand), the wrong player continues, e.g. the morning news plays while I was already listening to a podcast on Spotify, etc.

How can I force Android to always continue the media player I listened to most recently?
Alternatively, is there a voice command to select a specific player?